# Is a contract valid if only the husband is named on the contract but the wife signed her name on it?

Tags: contract-law

I, unfortunately, signed up for a 6 month personal training contract. I was super excited about it but the only trainer at the gym went to another location. I am only interested in working out at this particular gym and was told before I signed that he would be my trainer since he is the only one there. I would have never signed the contract otherwise. The trainer was transferred after I signed my contract and now I am getting the runaround.

The gym account is in my husbands name and I am added on as a family member. The personal training contract has only my husbands name listed. I initialed and signed my name on the contract, my husband was not present. Is the contract valid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the person named in an agreement is not the person who signed, is the agreement enforceable?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46202/if-the-person-named-in-an-agreement-is-not-the-person-who-signed-is-the-agreeme)

Answer (score 0):

> Is the contract valid?

The contract is valid and enforceable unless your husband disputes it.

The difficult part in your situation is whether you (or your husband) have the ability to prove that the gym's representations about its trainer are what induced you to enter the contract. This detail might or might not be ascertainable from the contract.

If that detail is not addressed in the contract, inducement could be proved by pointing to the relevant communications you had with the gym *prior to* signing the contract and/or any record reflecting the gym's representation(s) that he would be your trainer "since he is the only one there".

Many contracts contain language to the effect of superseding "*any prior or contemporaneous agreements between the parties*". If that is the case with yours, arguing and proving inducement might be insufficient for you to prevail at law.

Comment: The parol evidence rule generally prevents prior representations being terms of a contract even in the absence of such a clause. Prior representations are then only relevant for voiding the contract for misrepresentation

Comment: @DaleM I agree. But I gather that the OP's concern as to the validity of the contract refers only (?) to the issue of husband's name with the OP's signature. Other than that, it is palpable from her wording that she would rather not be stuck with the contract/gym, which is why I then focused on the matter of proving inducement by material misrepresentation so she can avail herself of [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](https://www.fbcoverup.com/docs/library/1981-Restatement-Second-of-Contracts-1981.pdf) at § 162(2), 164, and 167.

Comment: @DaleM See also [*Iafolla v. Douglas Pocahontas*, 250 S.E.2d 128,135 (1978)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1978378250se2d1281372) ("*parole evidence rule is [...] difficult to apply in individual cases since fraud, mistake, and misrepresentation are always equitable defenses to the literal enforcement of a written contract [...]*"). There the opinion states that the application of parole evidence depends on "*the degree to which the parties are commercial parties represented by counsel*". It is very unlikely that the OP was represented by counsel when entering the contract.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I got this resolved without having to get nasty.  I went up there and spoke with the "VP" and was given a temporary solution.  My husband was not happy with that so he left work and drove up there while the "VP" was still there.  The "VP" told my husband that everything was resolved. My husband stated "Not to my liking"  and was able to get the contract cancelled just like that.